# Sequence attribute manipulation in Object Oriented Database?

Tags: database

What is the efficient way of handling 'sequence object' in Object Oriented Database. I am using 'Versand' Database. Is there any direct Database calls available to handle the sequence objects'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the type of objects are in database is purely depends on the schema what we were used. If there is any sequential attributes we can use recursion to handle it. There is direct 'sequence object' handling APIs are available for versand Database.